# How to display multiple number of TextViews inside each row in ListView programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview, listitem

as I am new in Android, facing an issue with my App. I have to show multiple no. of TextViews inside each row of ListView as Each row can have different no. of TextViews. Please Help me to create TextView inside row Programatically and display text inside every row according to dataCount. 
Say....i have to create a row( LinearLayout, that is vertically oriented) having multiple no. of String values from ArrayList and need to create a single textview that can display data for ArrayList but my problem is that each row of listview have different no. of ArrayList count and ArrayList values. how can i solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have already done.. and in which part you are stuck..

Comment: Does each row has same number of textviews? Have you tried looking adapters (Baseadapter must be good).

Comment: @SKT no each row has different number of textviews and the data is not static. say if one row has 4 textviews then later on it can change according to the data size.i already tried BaseAdapter, it can show dynamic listview but static row view that has fixed number of elements .

Answer (score 0):

Instat of Linear layout You can use table layout.

```
           TableRow newRow;
           TableLayout tbl;
           int length=10; //As your wish;
           EditText[] ex = new EditText[length];
           for(t=0;t<length;t++){
                 newRow = (TableRow) new TableRow(this);
                 newRow.setClickable(true);
                 ex[t]=(EditText) new EditText(this);
                 newRow.addView(ex[t]);
                 newRow.setId(t);
                 tbl.addView(newRow);  
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> list = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Set hashmap key as index and value of string array list now pass to list adapter on adapter "getView()" method get position wise hashmap data and get their value,iterate value ArrayList as size make as no of TextView add on list item row layout.